# Linux, do I need if, else, or statements to accomplish automation of compiling programs from source

Tags: linux, bash, automation

I am wondering what would be the best way to write a bash script to install packages from source, would it even be needed to go in depth with how to automate the task?

For example let's say I want to compile apache

```
cd /path/httpd
./configure -arguments here -augment here -blah blah
make
make install
```

This process would be completely automated, no human interaction. Would it be fine to simply pass the arguments like shown above or do you think it should be more in depth with else statements and so forth?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know by advance that you have the prerequisite, you can do this.

This is how works [archlinux](/questions/tagged/archlinux) `PKGBUILD`s.

You can use CI-CD in your gitlab/github to test that the compilation is successful.

If you are unsure, then you need to add some conditions:

```bash
trap 'echo >&2 "Encountered an error"; exit 1' ERR
cd /path/httpd
./configure -arguments here -augment here -blah blah
make
make install
```

or

```bash
set -e
cd /path/httpd 
./configure -arguments here -augment here -blah blah
make
make install
```

or using boolean logic:

```bash
cd /path/httpd && 
./configure -arguments here -augment here -blah blah &&
make &&
make install
```

each command need to be successful to run the next one.